# how to achieve overload in typescript

Tags: typescript, overloading

I konw there is a way in typescript like this:

```
function foo(arg: number): string;
function foo(arg: string): number;
function foo(): any {
  if (typeof arguments[0] === "string") {
    return +arguments[0];
  } else {
    return arguments[0].toString();
  }
}

foo(1)       // '1'
foo("hello") // NaN 
foo("2")     // 2
```

But when I have same number of parameters and each parameter is custom type, like this

```
interface Dog {
  run: number;
}

interface Bird {
  fly: number;
}

function foo(arg: Dog): number;
function foo(arg: Bird): number;
function foo(): any {
}
```

How can I tell the difference between these parameters

Comment: By checking if `arg.run` or `arg.fly` exist.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript is JavaScript, so you basically have to do the same thing. In order to make your compiler happy, you can implement type guards.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards

```
function isDog(pet: Dog | Bird): pet is Dog {
  return 'run' in pet
}
```

You can use these in your code to tell TypeScript that you've validated the type for runtime.

```
function foo(arg?: Dog | Bird): void | number {
  if(arg) {
    if(isDog(arg)) {
      return arg.run;
    } else {
      return arg.fly;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: A side note: `return 'run' in pet;` would do as well and is slightly more concise and (subjectively) semantically correct.

Comment: Yeah, I just copied the example from TypeScript's documentation and changed fish to dog.